# Horizontal alignment of long equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, amsmath

I hope that the following question is not a duplicate but I could not find a definite answer.

I'm trying to obtain the the same result as Formula (1) in the picture next, but I feel that my approach is not optimal and somewhat dirty.

[image]

I produced the output with the following code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
X & = \{ x \mid \text{a very very very long condition} \} \cup \\
  & \phantom{{}={}} \{ y \mid \text{another very very very long condition} \}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
X & = \{ x \mid \text{a very very very long condition} \} \cup \\
& \quad \{ y \mid \text{another very very very long condition} \}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
X = & \{ x \mid \text{a very very very long condition} \} \cup \\
  & \{ y \mid \text{another very very very long condition} \}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
X = 
\begin{array}[t]{l}
  \{ x \mid \text{a very very very long condition} \} \cup \\
  \{ y \mid \text{another very very very long condition} \}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Formula (1) is the output I desire. However, I can't imagine that using  `\phantom` is the right way to go.

Formula (2) is according to the examples in the amsmath package documentation. And it looks ugly.

Formula (3) is better, but the kerning is wrong. However, I somehow feel that using the alignment in this way is the right approach.

Finally, Formula (4) uses an array, but also here the kerning is screwed.

Can anyone hint me in the right direction? Thanx!

Comment: The right way to write it inside `aligned` is: `\begin{aligned} X  = {} & \{ x \mid \text{a very very very long condition} \} \cup \\ & \{ y \mid \text{another very very very long condition} \} \end{aligned}`

Comment: I would agree that #3 is the idiomatic way, but I don't see the issue with kerning that you see, I suppose.  At least in the picture, it's unnoticeable (to the point that I don't see it at all).

Comment: @SeanAllred -- take a closer look.  in #3 there is no space between the equals sign and what follows.  this is wrong.  only #1 has the desired (proper) spacing.

Comment: @barbarabeeton oh goodness, how did I miss that? Well, using `\phantom` isn't all *that* hacky---this might be legitimate use. (For laziness' sake, something tells me you can add an empty group after `=` in #3 to achieve the effect---it's less typing.)

Comment: @SeanAllred there's no need in this case for `\phantom`... See my comment above. Should I post it as an answer?

Comment: @karlkoeller perhaps an answer then? :-)

Comment: I would say that the second line should not be aligned with the corresponding expression on the first line but indented relative to that expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In these cases there is no need at all for `\phantom` commands.

To ensure the correct spacing when binary relations or operators are involved, it suffices to use an empty group `{}`.

Infact, the code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
X  = {} & \{ x \mid \text{a very very very long condition} \} \cup {} \\            
        & \{ y \mid \text{another very very very long condition} \}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

gives the desired spacing:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this solution gives the right output and "feels right" ;) I guess that I should also use `\cup {} \\ ` rather than just `\cup \\ ` to get a proper spacing?!

Comment: @Dan Sorry, I've been notified about your original comment, so I didn't see the edit. The answer is: yes, of course (I was going to bed and I didn't even notice that the first line ends with `\cup`...). I've added it in the answer, too.